# How to responsively arrange an SVG tag to the above of the video tag's real playing area exactly?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive-design, html5-video

[image]

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls src="test.mp4"></video>
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute; left:0px; background:gray; opacity:0.5; pointer-events: none;"></svg>

<script>
    //some test code
    let v = document.getElementById("video");
    const testHandler = () => {
        let v_w = v.videoWidth;
        let v_h = v.videoHeight;
        let c_w = v.clientWidth;
        let c_h = v.clientHeight;
        console.log(v_w, v_h, c_w, c_h);
    }
    v.addEventListener('loadeddata', testHandler);
</script>
```

My purpose is to responsively arrange an SVG tag to the above of the video tag's real playing area exactly.
To understand current situations easily I styled the SVG area with a gray background and 0.5's opacity.
The green rectangle is a video and SVG tag area and the red rectangle is a real playing area. In other words, it's my target area.

**Firstly**, I want to know an effective method to get real playing area (red rectangle) coordinates.
**Secondly**, I want to know a responsive design skill to arrange an SVG tag to the above of the real playing area exactly.

Comment: Not sure how you can get that red area. Requesting the width and height of the video element will give you the dimensions of the green bordered area - after all, you specified that you want the `video` element itself to be this big. Guess you would have to dive deeper into the actual properties of the playing video file, and hope that you could read its original w&h from there somewhere …

Comment: If you know the actual video stream’s width and height upfront, then you can use the “padding-bottom hack” to span up a container element with the right aspect ratio, and then simply position video and svg in there absolute. (All four corner coordinates set to 0, width & height to auto.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
It just needs to calculate the video ratio and some offset values of the tags.

```
<video id="video" width="100%" height="100%" controls src="test.mp4"></video>
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%" style="position: absolute; left:0px; background:gray; opacity:0.5; pointer-events: none;"></svg>

<script>
    const svgHandler = (e) => {
        let v = document.getElementById("video");

        let v_w = v.videoWidth;
        let v_h = v.videoHeight;
        let c_w = v.clientWidth;
        let c_h = v.clientHeight;

        let v_rate = v_h / v_w;
        let c_rate = c_h / c_w;

        // 1. get real playing area

        let r_w;
        let r_h;

        if (v_rate < c_rate) {
            r_w = c_w;
            r_h = c_w * v_rate;
        } else {
            r_h = c_h;
            r_w = parseInt(r_h / v_rate);
        }

        // 2. arrange an SVG tag to the above of the real playing area

        let v_off = getOffset(v);

        let left_padding = (c_w - r_w) / 2 + v_off.left;
        if (e.type == "loadeddata") {
            let v_panel_off = getOffset(document.body);
            left_padding += v_panel_off.left;
        }

        let top_padding = (c_h - r_h) / 2 + v_off.top;

        let s = document.getElementById("svg");
        s.style.position = 'absolute';
        s.style.top = parseInt(top_padding);
        s.style.left = parseInt(left_padding);
        s.style.width = parseInt(r_w);
        s.style.height = parseInt(r_h);
        s.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }

    const getOffset = (el) => {
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
            top: rect.top + window.scrollY
        };
    }

    document.getElementById("video").addEventListener('loadeddata', svgHandler);
    window.onresize = svgHandler;
</script>
```